# extract data from listview to variable in android project (adapter to variable)

Tags: java, android, variables, tableview, logcat

need to extract the data from list view adapter to String variable in android studio.

at the moment it sends everything to tableview columns i need it to send to android studio logcat or place them in variable so i can use it else where within app.

```
  lvMsg = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMsg);

    // Create Inbox box URI
    Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

    // List required columns
    String[] reqCols = new String[]{"_id", "address", "body"};

    // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content
    // Provider
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    // Fetch Inbox SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
    Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, null, null, null);

    System.out.println(c);

    // Attached Cursor with adapter and display in listview
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c, new String[]{"body", "address"}, new int[]{
            R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber
    });

    lvMsg.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to instantiate a cursor and get the item from you SimpleCursorAdapter using the method getItem(int position) on SimpleCursorAdapter.

Cursor cursor =  (Cursor)adapter.getItem(position)

Once you have the cursor do something like follows.

```
boolean cursorMove = cursor.moveToFirst();
if (cursorMove)
{
   while(cursorMove)
   {
     String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data"));
     // your logic here on data
     cursorMove = cursor.moveToNext()
   }
}
cursor.close();
```

[CursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#getItem(int))

[Cursor Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)